# Eclipse проект не видит файл

Tags: spring, maven, eclipse

В проекте есть класс (файл), который этот проект будто не видит, так как не реагирует на изменения в нем: если в файле допустить даже несколько грубых синтаксических ошибок (например написать посреди файла `павыпып`), то проект все равно компилируется без ошибок и запускается.
Класс находится в одной из папок проекта. В среде разработки слева в дереве проекта тоже отображается.
Пробовал добавлять его через Build Path>Configure Build Path>Libraries>Add Class Folder, не помогает.
Возможно дело в том, что в проекте было два почти одинаковых класса с одной и той же функцией. Один я удалил.
Как добавить оставшийся файл в проект?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD. пробовал в методы этого класса вставлять `System.out.println` для проверки - ничего не выводится.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Откройте файл и приведите скриншот с содержимым файла и обозревателя проекта (Project Explorer).

Comment: А файл MvcConfig, стало быть, видит? Или тоже что-то непонятное?

Comment: Блин, проверил - тоже не видит. Тоже не реагирует на изменения.

Comment: Сам со Spring не знаком, но предполагаю, что проблема в конфигурации. Также имена пакетов у Вас какие-то странные... Может быть Вы их переименовывали?

Comment: Ничего не переименовывал. Да и ошибка должна выводится при переименовании вроде.

Comment: В таком случае нужно ждать знающих людей, но если до сих пор никто не заинтересовался, то скорее всего ждать ответ не вариант.

Comment: Да я уже пересоздал проект, делаю по-новой. Пока все работает.

Comment: Сравните два проекта между собой , чтоб найти разницу и соответственно причину. Если что-то найдёте, то оформите как ответ - это поможет в дальнейшем остальным, кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой.